# why SparkSession is not available in Spark2.3

Tags: apache-spark

I have Spark2.3 installed on my cluster, here is the output when I run `spark2-shell`:

```
> Spark context available as 'sc' (master = yarn, app id =
> application_1549677994084_2179). Spark session available as 'spark'.
> Welcome to
>       ____              __
>      / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
>     _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/    /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.0.cloudera3
>       /_/
> 
> Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java
> 1.8.0_121)
```

and errors out here:

```
> scala> val spark = new SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
> <console>:25: error: not found: value SparkSession
>        val spark = new SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
>                        ^
```

I then imported SparkSession as below:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

scala> val spark = new SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
<console>:26: error: type builder is not a member of object org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
       val spark = new SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
                                    ^

scala>
```

It works with

`val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)`

```
scala> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@7a364e1c
```

Why SparkSession is not working here for the Spark2?

Thank you.

Comment: Try using Val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spark shell, you should use scala, and that will be

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate()
```

without new before SparkSession.

You can try this example [Self Contained Applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications)

Answer (score 1):

Spark Session comes default with Spark-shell. Please check your screenshot.'

**Spark context available as 'sc' (master = yarn, app id =

> application_1549677994084_2179). Spark session available as 'spark'.**

You can use spark.sql or spark.read directly